# ASP.NET MVC - How to Treat Duplicate in Excel Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am uploading Excel file and save into my database using ASP.NET MVC. I succeeded in:

1. Importing the Excel file
2. Save in to database

See my Controller below

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult ImportCountriesExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        string data = "";
        var notif = new UINotificationViewModel()
        {
            notif_message = "Record Saved successfully",
            notif_type = NotificationType.SUCCESS,
        };
        var bodsList = new List<COUNTRIES>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            // tdata.ExecuteCommand("truncate table OtherCompanyAssets");  
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];
            if (true)//FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                try { 
                string message = "";
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(FileUpload.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    // if(currentSheet.Count)
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                            var bod = new COUNTRIES();
                            bod.COUNTRY_CODE = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                            if (bod.COUNTRY_CODE == "")
                                message += "<li> Country Code is empty at row " + rowIterator + "</li>";
                            bod.COUNTRY_NAME = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value);
                            if (bod.COUNTRY_NAME == "")
                                message += "<li> Country Name is empty at row " + rowIterator + "</li>";
                            if (bod.COUNTRY_DESC == "")
                                message += "<li> Country Desc is empty at row " + rowIterator + "</li>";
                            bodsList.Add(bod);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var item in bodsList)
                {
                    _countriesService.AddCountry(item);
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    notif.notif_message = "Application error, Contact the Administrator";
                    notif.notif_type = NotificationType.ERROR;
                }
                TempData["notif"] = notif;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                notif.notif_type = NotificationType.ERROR;
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data += "<ul>";
                data += "<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>";
                data += "</ul>";
                notif.notif_message = data;
                TempData["notif"] = notif;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                //return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data += "<ul>";
            if (FileUpload == null) data += "<li>Please choose Excel file</li>";
            data += "</ul>";
            notif.notif_message = data;
            TempData["notif"] = notif;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The issue I have is this

1. Some of the import have white spaces
2. It allows duplicate

**Please how do I:**

1. Remove white spaces using Trim
2. Whenever there is duplicate (If the record already exist), it should be filtered based on COUNTRY_CODE and COUNTRY_NAME. Then the system should should the list of records that already exist. It will ask the user the ones he wants to update or allow to duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preventing duplicate, you can read all existing items from the database and store that in a dictionary and while you iterate through each item from the excel rows, check against the dictionary to see if it exist, if not add to the database and add to the dictionary.

```
var countryDict=db.Countries.ToDictionary(a => a.Code, a => a.Name);
var duplicateItems = new List<string>();

//your existing code goes here
for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
{
   var countryCode = "Read this from the excel cell";
   var countryName = "Read this from the excel cell";

   if (countryDict.ContainsKey(countryCode))
   {
      duplicateItems.Add(countryCode);
   }
   else
   {
       countryDict.Add(countryCode,countryName);
      //existing code to save
   }
}
if(duplicateItems.Any()
{
   //This means duplicates exist
}
```

Trim is just a method you can call on string to remove white spaces, both leading and trailing. Make sure you are not calling it on NULL.

```
var trimmedValue= someStringVariableWhichCouldBeNull?.Trim();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1. How do I give the user the choice to determine what he wants to do with duplicate (to replace the existing or to save a new or to not to save it at all). 2. How do I apply the **var trimmedValue= someStringVariableWhichCouldBeNull?.Trim()** in practical terms.

Comment: you can render a view which displays `duplicateItems` and ask user what to do.  I do not under stand what you mean by  **How do I apply the var trimmedValue= someStringVariableWhichCouldBeNull?.Trim() in practical terms.** ?  just call Trim method on whatever string value you want